# Format the Data

Tags: oracle

Need to format the data in a different way. Like I'm getting the data in this way

`('East','West','North','South')` however, need to represent the data in another way. In this way

`('East,West,North,South')` we need to represent the data. Is it possible we can do this using

regexp_replace.If yes, please guide.

Comment: It would help if you showed how you are getting the data now - the query you are running, and the raw data from your table(s). It isn't clear if you currently have a single string value, which includes the parentheses and single quotes; or if you get multiple values (rows? columns?) and have just listed them in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE('(''East'',''West'',''North'',''South'')',
                 '('','')', ', ') "REGEXP_REPLACE"
  FROM DUAL;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f8db964494edce2f85878878e03a3df3)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions; simple `REPLACE` (line #3) is enough.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select q'[('East','West','North','South')]' from dual)
  3  select replace(col, q'[',']', ',') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
-------------------------
('East,West,North,South')

SQL>
```